# Side condition in generalisation rule and axiom schemata

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

I am studying formal proofs of first order logic, in particular the meta-theorem of generalisation:

**Generalisation:** $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ and $x$ does not occur free in any formula of $\Gamma$ then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \phi$

My question is about the side condition: I understand some simple counterexamples which show that the rule is unsound without the side condition. But I have questions about theories with *axiom schemata*, for example the induction axiom in Peano arithmetic (PA):

- If an axiom schema allows an instantiation with free variable $x$, does that mean the generalisation rule cannot be applied to $x$?
- In particular in PA, is there a restriction that the induction axiom can only be instantiated with formulae that have only the "induction variable" as free variable?

Comment: I don't understand your first question. PA is a theory, i.e. a set of sentences. That means it's the kind of thing that goes in place of $\Gamma$ in $\Gamma\vdash \phi$. The instances of the induction schema are sentences - they don't have free variables.

Comment: With regard to the second question, the induction schema is usually phrased so that it can be instantiated with formulas that have extra free variables (parameters). But then these extra variables are universally quantified, as is shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic). If you're using a different definition of PA, you should say what it is.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that a theory by definition only contains closed formulae. So the side condition never applies to axiom schemata. But that also means that this formulation of the induction axiom is slightly imprecise:

$$
(\phi(0) \land \forall x \phi(x) \implies \phi(s(x))) \implies \forall x \phi(x)
$$

Where $x \in free(\phi)$.

It should say $free(\phi) = \{x\}$ instead?

Comment: Well, by some conventions (which I must say I disapprove of!), it's ok for axioms to have free variables: they have the same meaning as the sentences obtained by universally quantifying the remaining free variables. You should check the conventions of the sources you're reading.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for the help!